# How to block calls on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

I have the first Apple iPhone 4.0, it does not have the "i" with the circle around it that I can tap and access a means to block a "contact" number in my phone. I've tried every option I know of....is there ANY way I can block a caller or do I have to buy a new phone just to block a call?

Answer (score 1):

The call blocking feature was added in iOS 7, which your iPhone can run.

iOS7 allows you to block calls and messages from particular contact or number. This feature, included by default, even allows you to block messages and calls performed on FaceTime.

Procedure:

- Open the Contacts app
- Select the contact you want to block and scroll to the bottom of the contact info page.
- Click "Block Contact".

Comment: I don't get it because my iPhone 4.0 does not have that feature...push contact (even edit contact) scrolled down, no "block contact" Is shown. Even went thru settings for contacts & phone....no option. Any help?

Comment: What iOS is it running?

Comment: Lol,...I have no clue what-so-ever...how could I even find out? Would the model of my phone help to answer my question?

Comment: The model number tells us nothing - but my guess is you're still on iOS 6. Try Settings > General > About... & it's listed under Version [assuming that info hasn't moved too far in the last 3 years]

Comment: All it says in "version" is..4.0(8A293)

Comment: Ye gods, that's still on iOS 4, never been updated since the day it was bought in 2010. Then your first challenge is to get it up to iOS 7, which will have to be done using a computer running iTunes. Over-the-air updates were a much later innovation. I would very seriously recommend you back it up to that computer first, using Encryption, as that will preserve all your passwords etc in case of disaster.

Comment: On second thoughts... I wouldn't. I'd just abandon the idea of being able to block callers on it - the chances of any of your apps still working after updating that far are extremely remote & you may just be creating more problems for yourself than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for all your help...issue solved...buying a new phone today!

Comment: hehe - welcome, wish you luck :-)